# Model won't render

Tags: javascript, three.js

I been trying to get my model in blender into my website. I've tried using different tutorials and I've checked to see if my model works outside of three.js and it works So If I'm missing something any help would be much appreciated. I'm thinking maybe it's something I have to download But I can't seem to find anything.

````
import {GLTFLoader} from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.118.1/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import {OrbitControls} from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.118/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';


class BasicWorldDemo {
  constructor() {
    this._Initialize();
  }

  _Initialize() {
    this._threejs = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true,
    });
    this._threejs.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    this._threejs.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
    this._threejs.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    this._threejs.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    document.body.appendChild(this._threejs.domElement);

    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      this._OnWindowResize();
    }, false);

    const fov = 60;
    const aspect = 1920 / 1080;
    const near = 1.0;
    const far = 1000.0;
    this._camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
    this._camera.position.set(75, 20, 0);

    this._scene = new THREE.Scene();

    let light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF, 1.0);
    light.position.set(20, 100, 10);
    light.target.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    light.castShadow = true;
    light.shadow.bias = -0.001;
    light.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
    light.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;
    light.shadow.camera.near = 0.1;
    light.shadow.camera.far = 500.0;
    light.shadow.camera.near = 0.5;
    light.shadow.camera.far = 500.0;
    light.shadow.camera.left = 100;
    light.shadow.camera.right = -100;
    light.shadow.camera.top = 100;
    light.shadow.camera.bottom = -100;
    this._scene.add(light);

    light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x101010);
    this._scene.add(light);

    const controls = new OrbitControls(
      this._camera, this._threejs.domElement);
    controls.target.set(0, 20, 0);
    controls.update();

    const loader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
    const texture = loader.load([
        './resources/posx.jpg',
        './resources/negx.jpg',
        './resources/posy.jpg',
        './resources/negy.jpg',
        './resources/posz.jpg',
        './resources/negz.jpg',
    ]);
    this._scene.background = texture;

    const plane = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100, 10, 10),
        new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
            color: 0xFFFFFF,
          }));
    plane.castShadow = false;
    plane.receiveShadow = true;
    plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
    this._scene.add(plane);

    // const box = new THREE.Mesh(
    //   new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2),
    //   new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    //       color: 0xFFFFFF,
    //   }));
    // box.position.set(0, 1, 0);
    // box.castShadow = true;
    // box.receiveShadow = true;
    // this._scene.add(box);

    // for (let x = -8; x < 8; x++) {
    //   for (let y = -8; y < 8; y++) {
    //     const box = new THREE.Mesh(
    //       new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2),
    //       new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    //           color: 0x808080,
    //       }));
    //     box.position.set(Math.random() + x * 5, Math.random() * 4.0 + 2.0, Math.random() + y * 5);
    //     box.castShadow = true;
    //     box.receiveShadow = true;
    //     this._scene.add(box);
    //   }
    // }

    // // const box = new THREE.Mesh(
    // //   new THREE.SphereGeometry(2, 32, 32),
    // //   new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    // //       color: 0xFFFFFF,
    // //       wireframe: true,
    // //       wireframeLinewidth: 4,
    // //   }));
    // // box.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    // // box.castShadow = true;
    // // box.receiveShadow = true;
    // // this._scene.add(box);

    this._RAF();
  }

  _LoadModel() { 
      const loader = new GLTFLoader();
      loader.load('./resources/untitled.glb',  (gltf) => {
          gltf.Scene.traverse(c => {
              c.castShadow = true;
          });
          this._scene.add(gltf.scene);
      });
  }

  _OnWindowResize() {
    this._camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    this._camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    this._threejs.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  }

  _RAF() {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      this._threejs.render(this._scene, this._camera);
      this._RAF();
    });
  }
}


let _APP = null;

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  _APP = new BasicWorldDemo();
});```
````

Comment: Any errors that you can show us?

Comment: that's the thing I'm not getting any errors so I'm completely in the dark

Comment: Have you tried to load the model in three.js/editor? Could you share the model?

Comment: Yeah sure But how would I share it

Comment: any fileshare like wetransfer would be ok

Comment: I'm trying to add the link but It says something about a URL shorteners

Comment: But I don't think that would solve the problem any way I've tried multiple models to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple problems.

#### Easy Fixes

First, your `traverse` call is on `gltf.Scene` (with a capital `S`). This capitalized property name is incorrect, and I'm surprised your browser doesn't throw an error over it. Use `gltf.scene` like you did to add it to your scene.

Next, the code you shared never calls `_LoadModel`. This could be a big reason why your model isn't showing up, unless you're calling it somewhere else.

#### Other Notes

I've never seen anything structured like this, but other than the issues I pointed out, it *should* work. If not, consider simplifying some of your ideas here, like moving everything from `_Initialize` into `constructor`, and re-organizing your animation loop to not create a new function each iteration. It's entirely possible you're losing your scope somewhere.